# Resize position and height of my own google chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a problem with resize google chrome extension I can't change default height size and position but with width it can be possible

Could somebody help me with this problem to change default height of google chrome extension popup,
possible i need that popup will be 100vh

Comment: Just set the height on `body`. The maximum is 600px.